# Discord pycord librariy, Commands have synced twice

Tags: python, pycord

I have managed to sync my commands/cogs twice.
here is my code (Error, Application command names must be unique)

```
<pre>import discord
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import slash_command

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>', intents=discord.Intents.all(),debug_guilds=[964126154774679582,740616442034258002,965533467557371944], activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name='Over The Felbcord'))
load_dotenv()
directories = ["./commands", "./Embeds"]

for directory in directories:
   for filename in os.listdir(directory):
      if filename.endswith(".py"):
       bot.load_extension(f"{directory[2:]}.{filename[:-3]}")
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Connected to bot: {}'.format(bot.user.name))

@bot.event
async def on_application_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await ctx.respond(error)
    else:
        raise error
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if bot.user in message.mentions:
        Welcome=discord.Embed(title="Felbot",url="https://github.com/VividBlue1/Felbcord-Py/tree/discord",description="Hello! I am a personal slave bot who helps around moderating and providing fun into the felbcord! \n If you have any questions about me feel free to ask @ignfoolish#0396 - my creator \n Join Felbcord here! \n https://discord.gg/ab5cxuQu7E",color=discord.Color.blue())
        Welcome.set_author(name="FelBot", url="https://github.com/VividBlue1/Felbcord-Py/tree/discord", icon_url="https://i.ibb.co/tz7VQJw/felb.jpg")
        await message.channel.send(embed=Welcome)
    await bot.process_commands(message)



bot.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))<pre>
```

It does start but no commands work because of this

Comment: @Robert Ive edited it, lmk if u need more code

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. This code could be trimmed down, and there are no slash commands in this code snippet. See [ask] for more information.

Comment: It isnt an issue with the slash commands themself, I synced them twice

Answer (score -1):

You didn't enabled the message content intent
To enable go to [discord developer portal](https://discord.dev/) and enable then come back to your code and do

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.message_content=True
```

Comment: ... i do have it enabled have done for ages

Comment: If you have all `Intents`, you certainly have the message_content `Intent` - that's what "all" means.